# Reduce height of div on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have an introduction div that calculates the browser window height and fills the screen and then the user can scroll down to the main page content below.

```
<body>
    <div id="intro"></div>
    <div id="main"></div>
</body>
```

I'm using the following JS to calculate the window height and attach it to the intro div:

```
  resizeWindow();
  $(window).resize(resizeWindow);

  function resizeWindow() {
    var ww = $(window).width();
    var bh = $(document).height();
    var wh = $(window).height();
    featureHeight = wh - 0;
    $('#intro').css({'height':featureHeight+'px'});

  }
```

What I'm attempting to do is to reduce the height of the intro div as the page scrolls and once the height reaches 0 and the user has reached the main div content, I can remove it so the user can no longer scroll back up to it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might use JSFiddle to provide us with an example of your code

Answer (score 0):

```
var $intro = $('#intro');
$('#container').scroll(function(){
    $intro.height($intro.height() + $intro.offset().top);
    $(document).scrollTop();
    if ($intro.height() <= 0) {
        $intro.remove();
    }
});
```

You essentially remove height from #intro until it reaches zero. It's a little reliant on the page being equal/smaller than the intro element itself, though.

http://jsfiddle.net/xvh4gbb2/1/